# TestCafe - Report Path

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, browser-automation

Is possible to use relative path for Reporters?

When i checked documentation of TestCafe i found this for screenshot but there is no pathPatern for reporters.

```
{ 
    "screenshots": { 
        "pathPattern": "${DATE}_${TIME}/test-${TEST_INDEX}/${USERAGENT}/${FILE_INDEX}.png" 
    } 
}
```

Is there any possibilites to use pathPattern for reporters in any version of TTestCafe.
I think this will be crucial function for all testers which are using TestCafe. It should be added into TestCafe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this enhancement request at https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3417. You can track progress there.